# @VisibleForTesting does not work as expected

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, annotations

I wanted to try the @VisibleForTesting annotation for a android unit-test - I have a class with one annotated method:

```
public class Foo {

  public void bar() {
  }

  @VisibleForTesting
  private void baz() {
  }
}
```

but in the unit-tests I still can only see bar - not baz

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The point of this annotation is that its convention and could be used in static code analysis.

Change the visibility of your method to `package`. In this case your method has reduced visibility for testing and is only visible to tests in the same package.

```
public class Foo {

  public void bar() {
  }

  @VisibleForTesting
  /* package */ void baz() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Having test class in same package as original class helped in adding unit test for package public method. Thanks

Comment: is `@VisibleForTesting` necessary if already in same package?